# Redux/state or Api call for updated value

Tags: reactjs, frontend

I want to know under which scenario we should call the data rendering api, as it consumes time (suggest me best practice)
if we **delete** data we should handle in state and only render the state/redux change, or call the data api for updated value.
, same for **edit existing,** add **new data** and other similar events

please suggest the best practice

Comment: For any CRUD operation you should keep the data in sync with backend(api).You can limit the api calls to increase the UI performance based on business use case.For state management also data is not persistent.So you should keep in mind at what point you need latest data from api and keep that in store.

Comment: thanks, but will this not effect the website performance if on every operation iam calling the updated data from backend.